# Is it possible to tell the stealth value of my current armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm evaluating different armor types and mods to figure out what works best as for my stealthy character. Unfortunately, in comparing one armor set with another I've only found anecdotal advice:

- less weight is better
- "lighter build" mods help
- "shadowed" mods help
- "padded" mods help

But I can't find any **numbers** for an actual comparison, so I'm reduced to saying things like "gosh, it seems like I'm getting detected a little less often now, I think, maybe".

Ideally I'd like to find out the stealth value/bonus/penalty of a specific piece of armor or—just as helpful—of my current character taking armor and other factors into account.

Is there a console command, or some less direct method, that will tell me how stealthy an item is? The [console command](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands#Stats_and_character_manipulation) `player.getav` will show current [character variables](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands#Character_variables), but I've only found two that sound promising, and neither changes when I switch armor:

- MovementNoiseMult
- Mod_StealthMove_AV

Comment: The brackets are one indicator. So, related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244115/108003 That's still not a hard number though

Comment: I was going to make a question similar to this, because I was also curious on "stealth effectiveness", but never got it worded in a way I liked. There are a bunch of questions that ask about the effectiveness of stealth that just get objective "this one seems better to me" answers, such as [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244010/does-carry-weight-affect-stealth) and [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244806/is-shadowed-armor-better-than-no-armor-for-sneaking). I hope the answer/method that comes out of this question can help answer some of those older ones.

Comment: the only thing i've found out of [this list](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3texxt/heres_a_table_of_actor_values/) is the invisibility value, but that only has to do with chameleon armor/stealth boys

Comment: I think "suspicious" must be part of this,

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding detection while sneaking relies on the same stuff as before; equipped armor weight, proximity to enemy, light levels and movement speed. The closest thing to a number value (assuming the armor has the same mod ie. padded, shadow ext) is the weight.  The lower the weight the better for sneaking.

There are no skills anymore, you can't invest into sneaking early on and play a ninja/sniper from the get go. You can grab stealth related perk as your Agility allows, but the essential sneaking tools (suppressors, agility stat, higher sneaking efficiency and better sneak attacks) are locked behind high levels, making stealth play a tedious chore.

As for the factions, Your best bet is to find the group Railroad, get the suppressed 10mm pistol which is one of the best in the game. after completing the initial joining quest and buy the suppressed sniper rifle they have on sale. Or else, you won't be able to play a sneaky ranged character when starting out.

Melee has an easier time when starting out since melee weapons are already "silent". They also have much higher sneak critical multipliers.

Speaking of multipliers, Ninja perk is bugged as of(1.30) and does not grant any bonus to melee sneak attacks at level 1. At level 2, it grants 4x multiplier instead of 5x. Level 3 works as intended with a 10x multiplier.

Blitz perk that is obtainable at 9 Agility and allows you to VATS into enemies from a distance with melee weapons is also a godsend, since otherwise you get immediately detected when you sneak into melee range at lower levels.

Comment: Only the first paragraph has anything to do with the question - and the info it provides is already specifically mentioned as too vague.