# Do companions benefit from wearing stealth armor in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I've equipped Cait with a stealth chest piece. In sneak mode, I can still see her.  But I can't tell if NPC's can see her or not.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific stealth effect, like Chameleon, or all of them in general? There's also muffled and shadowed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, companions do benefit from the effects of armors with the 'Chameleon' legendary effect. Below is an image from a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3v313g/psa_companions_use_chameleon_armor_same_as_the/) showing Piper with the chameleon effect.

[image: Invisible Piper]

This is also supported by a note on the [Legendary effects page of the Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_armor_effects).

There seems to be a couple of potential bugs reported with Chameleon on your companion.

1. Per the Fallout Wiki page: `Furthermore, it works on companions as well, although the effect will simply stop working fairly often with no apparent reason and no reliable fix, somewhat limiting its usefulness (especially given most companions' unpredictable sneak behavior). Unequipping and re-equipping a chameleon piece from a companion's equipped inventory fixes their chameleon armor's effect.`
2. Some users, [such as this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136912667628/), have reported that even after taking away the pieces with chameleon, their companion will go invisible when stationary and crouching.

Comment: What about Muffled and Shadowed?

Comment: Awesome response.  Just discovered stealth armor stacks so I'm adding an armor to me and my companion.  I can now see that Cait is in stealth mode.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @DCShannon I assumed he was referring to Chameleon because of context clues in his question. `I can see her, but I can't tell if NPC's can see her or not` points to him expecting her to be invisible, so I answered towards the Chameleon effect. I'm not sure about muffled and shadowed... I'll see if there is any info about it, but I've personally never been able to see a difference with those mods on companions. With how difficult it is to give a definitive 'how effective is stealth' answer, I doubt there is. This question is at least answerable in the Chameleon context.

Comment: @DCShannon If there were a good way to determine 'stealth effectiveness' on your character, or some variables accessible through console, you'd probably be able to do that analysis on your companion as well to get a better idea on Muffled/Shadowed. Unfortunately, [by the state of this unanswered question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248297/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-stealth-value-of-my-current-armor?rq=1), I'm not sure there is. :(