# Does Legendary Armour Benefit a Companion?

Tags: fallout-4

If you equip a piece of legendary armour onto a companion, do they get the benefits from that armour that you would normally get? Or would it just be a standard piece of armour to them? For example, I have a Combat Armor Right Leg that provides 15% less damage taken from humans. If I gave that to Piper, would she gain that benefit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3v99dx/does_legendary_armor_effects_take_effect_if/) with folks asking the same question, I found that your Companions DO benefit from most legendary armor effects.  I need to emphasize MOST though as they obviously do not benefit from increased AP / VATS hit chance ect... they also do not benefit from (+) Resistance benefits.  You can also upgrade companions armor with deep pockets and equip legendary gear with strength to increase their carrying capacities by a LOT (Paladin Danse or Strong could essentially be your pack mule slaves). I hope this info helped out!

Comment: I was surprised at the suggestion they don't benefit from resistances. The relevant quote from the linked discussion is "They don't benefit from +resistance mods. (I find this one weird and really hope it's a bug, unless I need to equip full set of given armour to get the listed bonus, player benefits from bonuses on per-piece basis)." That's not super convincing. I'm going to look for more evidence.

Comment: Don't see any more after a couple minutes. Shouldn't be too hard to test though, even on console. I'll try to remember to do so: put legendary resistance (such as Poisoner's) armor on a companion, dismiss them, target them in VATS with the awareness perk, check.

Comment: I tested this last night. Putting a Poisoner's left arm on X6-88 gave him 25 poison resistance, as reported by Awareness.

Comment: A particularly annoying one, companions seemingly don't benefit from "acrobat" (50% less falling damage). My PC has two "acrobat" pieces, so I can jump from anywhere and take no damage. I put the same gear on Curie and either Piper or Cait, and they both managed to fall off a building and require stim-packing like 5 minutes later. I *am* using a bunch of mods, including one that allows crafting legendaries, so it may be a bug with my game, rather than a default behavior.

Comment: Chameleon armor pieces do not give them the chameleon effect while standing still.

Comment: @LoreFriendly And crouching? I feel pretty confident I've seen a follower cloak when crouched. They don't spend much time standing still, though.

Comment: @DCShannon standing still and crouching as in stealth mode. I play on the PC and I just tested it. I have two pieces of chameleon armor. Gave one to my companion. Still visible AFAICT.

Comment: @DCShannon Actually this has already been [asked here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255149/do-companions-benefit-from-wearing-stealth-armor-in-fallout-4) and what I encountered has been listed as a bug.

Answer (score -1):

I regularly equip and use chameleon armor with my companions. Occasionally I need to unequip and re-equip it for it to continue to work